# ajax/jquery pulling data from db & selecting value from drop down

Tags: jquery, ajax

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3cBxR/)

i am have hard time with this one.....let me explain

i am pulling data from db with ajax and appended it to dataHolder div - until now every thing is ok - every user has Year - month - day -

now if want to give new date for instance for the first user peter - when i click on confirm the a tag i pick the year , month , day  ( this work only for the first user )

now if i want to give new date for second user alex- when i click on confirm
the a tag i pick only client id - but for the year and month and day is nothing

anyhelp please guys

//alert( year + month + day + cid); output only the user cid

let me show you the code for better understanding

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#dataHolder").on('click', '.set', function() {

        var cid = $(this).attr('id')
        var year = $('#year').val();
        var month = $('#month').val();
        var day = $('#day').val();

        //alert( year + month + day + cid);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'confirm.php?id=' + cid + '&year=' + year + '&month=' + month + '&day=' + day,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response)
            }
        });
    });

    $('#btn').hide();

    $('#myform').on('change', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var select = $('#select').val();
        // ** console.log(select);

        var datasholder = $('#dataHolder').html('');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'proccess.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                datasholder.append(data);
            }
        })
    })
})
```

// ** After the data pulled out down below

```
<div id="dataHolder">

    <table class="tablesorter bordered" id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr> 
                <th>No.</th>     
                <th>Client Name:</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>        
                <td>mohammed fathi</td>
                <td>

                    <input type="text" id="year" name="year" maxlength="4">&nbsp;

                    <select id="month" name="month">

                        <option value="">Select...</option>
                        <option value="01">January</option> 

                    </select>&nbsp;

                    <select style="width: 60px;" id="day" name="day">

                        <option value="">--</option>
                        <option value="01">01</option>
                        <option value="02">02</option>

                    </select>&nbsp;

                    <a style="cursor: pointer;" class="set" id="1">Confirm</a>  // ** confrim   
                </td>           
            </tr>  


            <tr>
                <td>1</td>        
                <td>mohammed fathi</td>
                <td>

                    <input type="text" id="year" name="year" maxlength="4">&nbsp;

                    <select id="month" name="month">

                        <option value="">Select...</option>
                        <option value="01">Jan</option> 
                        <option value="01">Feb</option> 

                    </select>&nbsp;

                    <select style="width: 60px;" id="day" name="day">

                        <option value="">--</option>
                        <option value="01">01</option>
                        <option value="02">02</option>

                    </select>&nbsp;

                    <a style="cursor: pointer;" class="set" id="2">Confirm</a>  // ** confrim   
                </td>           
            </tr> 


        </tbody>  
    </table>
</div>
```

//////// *********** Second update

$("#dataHolder").on('click','.set',function(){

```
              // do something

                 //var cid   = $(this).attr('id')
                 //var year  = $('#year').val();
                 //var month = $('#month').val();
                 //var day   = $('#day').val();

              var cid   = $(this).attr('id')
              var year  = $(this).siblings('.year').val();
              var month = $(this).siblings('.month').val();
              var day   = $(this).siblings('.day').val();


             alert( year + month + day + cid);

             $.ajax({
                url: 'confirm.php?id='+cid+'&year='+year+'&month='+month+'&day='+day, 
                type: "POST",
                success: function( response ){
                    console.log( response )
               }
            }); 
    });
```

Comment: IDs have to be unique, you can't repeat `id="year"`, etc. for each person.

Comment: thanks - Barmar - how i can solve this problem ?

Comment: also first ajax request should be 'get' instead of 'post' because you are exposing your data in url.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same IDs in each row. Change `id="year"` to `class="year"` (and the same for month and day). Then change the code to:

```
 var cid   = $(this).attr('id');
 var year  = $(this).siblings('.year').val();
 var month = $(this).siblings('.month').val();
 var day   = $(this).siblings('.day').val();
```

Comment: when i do alert it says NaN1

Comment: check out the update ... i have changed the all id's to class as well as for the html

Comment: yeah, i have noticed that- but i have changed it but it dose not work